# Red circle when crossover condition is met

Tags: pine-script

I'm creating a custom stochastic indicator and I would like to create a circle when the crossover k and d condition is met. However with the plotshape function is not working. What can I try next?

````
//@version=4
study(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")

periodK = input(14, title="K", minval=1)
periodD = input(3, title="D", minval=1)
smoothK = input(3, title="Smooth", minval=1)
k = sma(stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = sma(k, periodD)
    
plotshape(cross(k,d), title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)

plot(k, title="%K", color=#0094FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6A00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#606060)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#606060)
fill(h0, h1, color=#9915FF, transp=80, title="Background")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cross() is not a pine function

refer to crossover(a,b) or crossunder(a,b) which return true or false:

and you should feed the plotshape a value of K or D so it know where to absolute at:

```
Signal = crossover(K,D) or crossunder(K,D)    
plotshape(Signal? K :na, location=location.absolute)
```